# WebView bug/error/code mistake?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am having trouble with my WebView. When I call the data from firebase using the TextView it's fully working, but when I call the data from firebase using WebView (see the code below), the data doesn't display at all unless if I exit my app and run it again.

```
public static class LessonListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    String justifyTag = "<html><body style='text-align:justify;LINE-HEIGHT:20px;font-size:12px;padding-top:10px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;'>%s</body></html>";
    View mView;

    public LessonListViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setData_one(String data_one){

        //TextView post_lesson1 = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_lesson1);
        //post_lesson1.setText(data_one);


        WebView post_lesson1 = (WebView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_lesson1);
        String dataString = String.format(Locale.US, justifyTag, data_one);
        post_lesson1.loadDataWithBaseURL("", dataString, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");

    }

    public void setData_two(String data_two){
        //TextView post_lesson2 = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_lesson2);
        //post_lesson2.setText(data_two);
        WebView post_lesson2 = (WebView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_lesson2);
        String dataString = String.format(Locale.US, justifyTag, data_two);
        post_lesson2.loadDataWithBaseURL("", dataString, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");



    }



    public void setData_image (final Context ctx, final String data_image){
        final ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(data_image).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(post_image, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {

                Picasso.with(ctx).load(data_image).into(post_image);

            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: [Solved] I just fixed my xml layout from CardView to RelativeLayout. To be honest this took me half day lol.

Comment: If you solved it post the answer so we know it is fixed.